# How to prepare the training data for Support Vector Machine?

Tags: classification, svm, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

I'm currently doing some comparison of Naive Bayes Algorithm and Support Vector Machine classifying news to see each algorithm's accuracy.

I already know how to prepare the training data for Naive Bayes 
E.g this is my training set for Naive Bayes

- Sports Bayern end title race and reaffirm game's significance in
  strange times
- Culture Gadsby follows up her hit show Nanette with a swaggering set
  that blazes with well-earned confidence
- Lifestyle Unproven remedies proliferate in my community, even in the
  face of a deadly virus

For Naive Bayes, I already have tested the classifier and it seems to be working nice. But now I'm stuck with SVM, can someone give me tips on how should I transform e.g the above data to SVM for training? I have downloaded some training data on SVM format, I can see they're formatted with numbers. But I want to know the logic of how those numbers came up, are they random for each word or something?

I appreciate the time that you spent reading this, would be very thankful if someone could guide me to the right direction

Thanks